# mongokit index does not work

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, flask, mongokit

I am developing a Web application using Flask and MongoDB. And I use (Flask-)MongoKit to define a schema to validate my data.

In my database, there is a collection called "users" (see below) that contains a field "email". I try to create a unique index on that field as specified in the MongoKit documentation (http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/indexes.html). However, when I check the collection indexes via MongoDB client shell, there is no index "email" at all.

I found a similar issue on the net: "unique index does not work" (https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/issues/98)

Does someone has any idea why it does not work?

User collection:

```
@db.register
class User(Model):

    __collection__ = 'users'

    structure = {
        'first_name': basestring,
        'last_name': basestring,
        'email': basestring,
        'password': unicode,
        'registration_date': datetime,
    }

    required_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'registration_date']

    default_values = {
        'registration_date': datetime.utcnow,
    }

    # Create a unique index on the "email" field
    indexes = [
        {
            'fields': 'email',  # note: this may be an array
            'unique': True,     # only unique values are allowed 
            'ttl': 0,           # create index immediately
        },
    ]
```

db.users.getIndexes() output:

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "youthmind.users",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
]
```

Note that I also try without 'ttl':0, and I was able to create an index using the following piece of code:

```
db.users.create_index('email', unique=True)
```

I think this uses the pymongo Connection object directly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it exactly how you should be doing it.  Automatic index creation has been removed from MongoKit as of version 0.7.1 (maybe version 0.8?).  [Here](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/issues/44) is an issue for it.

The reason behind it is that the it would have to call `ensureIndex` on the collection.  The "ensure" part of the name makes it seem like it would check and then create the index if it doesn't exist, but a developer from Mongo said that it might still wind up (re-)creating the entire index, which could be terribly expensive.  The developer also said it should be considered an administrative task, instead of a development task.

The work around is to call `create_index` yourself on for each index in the list you've defined as part of an upgrade/create script.

Answer (score 3):

Right, you need to use separate script to recreate DB with indexes. It will be called if needed, not each time server runs. Example:

```
def recreatedb(uri, database_name):
    connection = Connection(uri)
    connection.drop_database(database_name)
    #noinspection PyStatementEffect
    connection[database_name]
    connection.register(_DOCUMENTS)
    for document_name, obj in connection._registered_documents.iteritems():
        obj.generate_index(connection[database_name][obj._obj_class.__collection__])
```

To prevent using database without indexes:

```
def init_engine(uri, database_name):
    global db
    connection = Connection(uri)
    if database_name not in connection.database_names():
        recreatedb(uri, database_name)
    connection.register(_DOCUMENTS)
    db = connection[database_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Flask-Script so it was easy to add Marboni's answer as a command to my manage script which is easy to run.

```
@manager.command
def setup_indexes():
    """
    create index for all the registered_documents
    """
    for doc in application.db.registered_documents:
        collection = application.db[doc.__collection__]
        doc.generate_index(collection)
```

I keep my database as member of app (application.db) for various admin stuff. Now whenever I add few index or change anything I run my manager command.

```
./manage.py setup_indexes
```

You can read more about manager module here 
http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/